# Javascript giving me Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined error

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have a file structure that looks like this:
[image]

My index.js has this code

```
const THREE = require("three")

var scene = new THREE.scene();
console.log(scene)
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="webgl-output">What the hell</div>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I did not use the tag { type : "modules } in my package.json. However, I am still getting the Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined error. May I know what is the reason? Thanks!

Error in my live server looks like this
[image]

This is my package.json if you are interested

```
{
  "name": "threejs-playground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.133.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: HTML note: load your script with `<script src="./index.js" async defer></script>` in the head element. We haven't had to put it "at the end of the document" for a good decade now. But with that said: yes, of course you'll get that error. Your index.js uses Node's `require()`, which isn't a think in the browser, nor is it part of the JS spec for that matter. It's Node's own flavour of module loading, so you'll either have to bundle for the browser (using esbuild or the like), or use ES module syntax (and then remember to use `type="module"` for your script tag, and remove `defer`)

Comment: Hello, I tried the solution, and I seem to be getting this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: My package.json do have "type":module" now

Comment: package.json only controls Node. It does not have any effect on how browsers work.

Comment: Okay giving my JS type="module" seemed to have done the trick, however i cant seem to import my package from the library

Comment: It is now giving me an error looking like this:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: We are not having a real time debugging chat: if you have a new situation, with new errors, [edit your post](/help/how-to-ask) so that everyone is up to date.

Comment: No problem, I shall do that, thanks for the tip

Comment: It sounds like you're very new to writing code for Node.js, in which case: Node.js does not work like the browser. At all. And code written for Node.js will almost certainly not load in the browser unless you _really_ know what you're doing (in which case you're almost certainly writing bad Node code, because it requires things that don't make sense for Node in order to satisfy the browser). This is why you write Node code, and then "transpile" it for use in the browser using tools like [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/). I recommend finding a modern tutorial for writing node+browser code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will look into it and understand how node works in the backend. I have managed to solved the issue by employing ur advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In addition to the above, I just want to point out that three.js documentation for installation has a good explanation of using it from CDN under "Install from CDN or static hosting" section here: https://threejs.org/docs/?q=orbit#manual/en/introduction/Installation with which you don't need to bundle and transpile the code

Comment: Thanks for ths @Deep, but i used npm install to install the three haha, i prefer to have the files locally for whatever reason.

Comment: Then consider that CDNs are the same idea. It's hosted for the browser remotely, your browser downloads it, but it downloads it _once_. After that, it's cached, and the browser loads the local copy until you clear your cache, just like how with Node you install things from NPM, until you need to update it, at which point you'll be redownloading it.